# What happens if i declared another variable with the same name in another file?

Tags: c

I have declared `int x` in **file one** and by mistake I declared another variable of type `char` with the same name `x` in **file two**, and I wait the compiler or the linker to give me an error, but there are no errors displayed. and when I use the debugger I see that `int x` is converted to `char x` , is that true?! and what actually happens here?!

Show this modification on my code:

**File One**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 50;  /** declare global variable called
                           x **/
int main()
{
    print();
    printf("      global in file one = %d",x);  /** Modification is just here **/
    return 0;
}
```

**File Two**

```
char x;   

void print(void)
{

    x = 100;
    printf("global in file two = %d ",x);
    return;

}
```

My expected results are = **global in file two = 100      global in file one = 50**

*but* The results are : **global in file two = 100      global in file one = 100**

When I use the debugger I see that `int x` is converted to `char x` , is that true?! and what actually happens here?

Comment: I am surprised that this even compiled. If you want to use a global with the same name in different files, declare both as `static`.

Comment: @Jon, the `char x` is a tentative definition, so compilation should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in troublesome territory here. Technically your program causes undefined behaviour. `char x` is a tentative definition, since it doesn't have an initializer.  That means the linker unifies it with the `int x` in the other file at link time.  It's a bit weird looking, since your two declarations have different types, but it appears to have successfully linked in your case.  Anyway, you have only one `x`, and luck is making it work the way you're seeing it (and little-endian architecture, probably).

If you want the two variables to be independent, make them `static`, and they'll be restricted to the scope of their respective translation units.

Comment: Would adding an initializer change anything?

Comment: @luserdroog, yes, adding an initializer to `char x` in file two will result in a duplicate symbol error at link time.

Comment: what is the rule of little-endian architecture here?!

Comment: That `100` fits in 8 bits, so your `int` and `char` accessing code output the same thing.

Comment: @CarlNorum I tried to make the variable x to overflow in file two, so I changed x = 100 to x= 1000 and the results are :
 global in file two = -24 global in file one = 232

Why it is printed signed in file two while it is printed as unsigned in file one although the format specifier for printf is the same in the two files which is %d

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.  You can watch the bit patterns in a debugger if you want to see exactly what's happening in your specific case.