# How throw a GCC error, if a global variable with the same name gets declared twice in a C/C++ file, but not static, extern, nor volatile?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, scope, global-variables

I [did run into the situation](https://github.com/plasmapper/modbus-esp-cpp/issues/2), that I declared two (separate) global variables with the same name in two separate files, but without using `static`, `volatile` nor `extern` on them.
One file was a .c and the other a .cpp file.

The compiler and build environment (GCC) was the ESP IDF and even the data types were different on these declarations.

mqtt_ssl.c:

```
esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client;
```

mb_master.cpp:

```
PL::ModbusClient client(port, PL::ModbusProtocol::rtu, 1);
```

During the runtime i experienced a lot of problems with reboots of the ESP32 until I found out, that the same name, of two actually separate variables, is causing the issue.
My guess is, that the compiler used the same memory-region for both of them.

I expected, that it gets handled as two separate objects with its own region in the memory, which is obviously not true.
After reading some questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663749/redefinition-error-doesnt-happen-in-external-source-file/) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991345/what-happens-if-i-declared-another-variable-with-the-same-name-in-another-file) is my understanding now is that the behavior is undefined, if a variable with the same name gets declared without `static`, `extern` or `volatile` in two separate C/C++ files.

It took me quite a while to figure that out.
If it is not allowed to declare it like this, why didn't the compiler/linker throw an error?
Is there an option for GCC to treat such a situation as error to prevent that situation in the future?

**Edit 1:**
This is a reproducible example with xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe (crosstool-NG esp-2021r2-patch3) 8.4.0.

app_main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_sub(void);

uint16_t test1;

void app_main(void)
{
    test1 = 1;
    printf("app_main:test1=%d\n", test1);
    test_sub();
    printf("app_main:test1=%d\n", test1);
}
```

test_sub.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int16_t test1;
void test_sub(void)
{
    test1 = 2;
    printf("test_sub:test1=%d\n", test1);
}
```

Result:

```
app_main:test1=1
test_sub:test1=2
app_main:test1=2
```

`test1` in `app_main()` got overwritten by `test_sub()`, because it had the same name in both files.

Comment: Why not redesign your software to not use globals at all. And fix the real issue? If you need a file with constants make a header file with `static const <T> value;` definitions. Tip to really get rid of globals : define an abstract base class with getters and use dependency injection.

Comment: There are no "two global variables with the same name" in the code that you've posted.

Comment: Compilers should issue a warning about shadowed variable names.

Comment: With the two lines of code you show there shouldn't be a problem. You have `mqtt_client` and `client`. They are not the same name.

Comment: And if you *do* have variables with the same name in different translation units, then the linker should give errors as it won't allow multiple definitions of the same name (although it won't care about the types).

Comment: "There are no 'two global variables with the same name' in the code that you've posted." - Thanks, I posted mistaktenly the new code with different names, I corrected this in the example code here to have the same name used as it was when I had the issue.

Comment: What version of GCC did you use and, if you add `-fno-common` to the compiler flags, does your build get a link error for a multiply-defined symbol? Do the two variables you show have the same name as the linker sees it or is one changed by C++ decoration? What happens if you change the one that should be only a declaration, not a definition, to start with `extern`? Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the option `--fno-common` is the actual answer of my question since it throws an error in this situation.  
It is set as default in GCC 10 and higher, but I use GCC 8.4 and there you have to set it as compiler option.
Please add this as answer, I will accept it as solution.
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client;` is a tentative definition. In spite of its name, it is not a definition, just a declaration, but it will cause a definition to be created at the end of the translation unit if there is no regular definition in the translation unit.

The C standard allows C implementations to choose how they resolve multiple definitions (because it says it does not define the behavior, so compilers and linkers may define it). Prior to GCC version 10, the default in GCC was to mark definitions from tentative definitions as “common,” meaning they could be coalesced with other definitions. This results in the linker not complaining about such multiple definitions.

Giving the `-fno-common` switch to GCC instructs it not to do this; definitions will not be marked as “common,” and the linker will complain if it sees multiple definitions.

Comment: I just did some more tests. If I declare the variable in the second file as `extern`, then the compiler accepts it, even when I use there a different datatype as on the first declaration.  
For example declared as `uint16` in main file and as `extern float` in other file.
This would lead to a similar issue, if the same name would get used with different types.
How raise a compiler error in this situation as well?

Comment: @MichaelUray: Re “How raise a compiler error in this situation as well?”: There is no fail-proof way to do this using only the compiler and linker; you would need to add additional checks to your project. To start, do not declare external identifiers in source files. Declare them in header files. That helps ensure the same declaration gets used in different places. Still, in complicated projects with various subprojects, there is nothing  completely preventing one subproject from declaring `foo` in its headers and another from declaring a different `foo` in its headers…

Comment: … except that, usually, each subproject will also define its own `foo`, and those multiple definitions will cause a link error (except when built using libraries rather than direct object files). This detection can fail when somebody puts a declaration in a subproject but fails to define it in that subproject. Testing the software usually catches such errors, especially separate testing of each subproject and other unit testing.

Comment: I usually put `extern` declarations in one header file to prevent such situations. In my case I added source files from separate example (MQTT and Modbus) codes to one project and randomly both had the same name used as global variable which causes me issues. What I am doing now is just for testing and for my understanding and I am wondering why the linker is able to check if there exists an external variable declaration when I declare it as extern, but it is not able to check if the datatype fits to it. It actually should be technically possible for the linker to check the datatype as well.

Answer (score -1):

Is your problem really that the variable is shaddowed? Often with global variables the problem can be that the variables are not initialized in the right order.